# generate programmatically text-symbols with ABAP

Tags: abap

I've created a program with FM: TR_TADIR_POPUP_ENTRY_E071. I am trying to generate at the same time text-symbols for this program.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Is the menu option `Goto -> Text elements -> Text Symbols` not available to you? Or are you wishing to do this programmatically? Please revise your question to be more clear.

Comment: No, i wanna do this programmatically ... while i generate the programme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's no standard interface for that. Check the ABAP statement `INSERT TEXTPOOL`. Documentation is placed [here](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapinsert_textpool.htm).

Before anything I recommend you to manually create a local program with text-symbols and in another program read the texts with [`READ TEXTPOOL`](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapread_textpool.htm) command to see what's the data structure. In that way you can build up the input data.

SAPLINK uses this technique also.